# extract specific number from string after a substring

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

extract number after "-PRJ-" from the input string.
Below DataWeave code is working OK with input 1 but failing for input 2, since it has a previous number before "-PRJ-".

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
fun projName (name)= flatten(name scan/\d/) joinBy "" first 6
---
projName(invoiceLines.account.name)
```

Inputs:

- Input case 1: "Media LLC-PRJ-**115503** IT T&E-8800 Information Technology"
- Input case 2: "Media-29 LLC-PRJ-**115548** IT T&E-8800 Information Technology"

The expected output for input 1 is `115503` and for input 2 is `115548`.

Comment: Is your string always `... LLC-PRJ-` and then 6 numbers?

Comment: it always has -PRJ- and 6 numbers, LLC Optional

Comment: Did the solution work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use function substringAfter() to get the string after "-PRJ-", then extract the first 6 characters of the resulting substring with first().

I created a function getProjectName() as an example. I'm using an array with both input strings to show the outputs for each.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/java
import * from dw::core::Strings
fun getProjectName(s)=substringAfter(s, "-PRJ-") first 6
---
payload map getProjectName($)
```

Input:

```json
[ 
    "Media LLC-PRJ-115503 IT T&E-8800 Information Technology",
    "Media-29 LLC-PRJ-115548 IT T&E-8800 Information Technology"
]
```

Output:

```json
[115503, 115548]
```